# minifyEnabled for certain package or my files only

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, couchbase-lite

I am writing an android project, and trying to compile it for release.
In my project i am using 3rd party projects such as couchbase-lite.

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

I want to use minifyEnabled=true in the gradle, but the signed APK fails to run,
It appears to be a problem with couchbase using reflection and failing to find one of the properties...

1. Is there a way to configure gradle to minifyEnabled only on my project files?
2. Can i configure it to minifyEnabled only certain packages?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can exclude classes that are using reflection and may cause troubles at run time using `-keep` rules in Proguard configuration file.

```
-keep public class com.example.somepackage.*
```

Using the rule above, all classes that match `public class com.example.somepackage.*` are excluded from being minified and obfuscated.

Comment: Could you elaborate how to `set minifyEnabled=false to build.gradle of your app's libraries.`? I assume adding to `build.gradle of your app` is just how we do it - add to `android { buildTypes { release { minifyEnabled true ... } } }`, right?

Comment: @BrianHong That was an old and rather incorrect answer, updated.

Comment: @frogatto Is it possible to do the other way around? Like by default, all all classes excluded, and include only certain classes.